# Fetch cursor in plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, cursor, plpgsql

After reading this link http://microjet.ath.cx/WebWiki/ResultPaginationWithPostgresql.html, I decided to using cursor for pagination. But it seems I don't know how to fetch the result in plpgsql.

This is my function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_pagination_custom_word_moderation(_moderation_id bigint, _is_black boolean, _index integer, _max_result integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(word_id bigint,
        word character varying,
        is_num_rlpcm boolean,
        is_word_bund boolean,
        note text,
        create_time timestamp without time zone,
        last_update timestamp without time zone) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE custom_word_moderation_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        word_id,
        word,
        is_num_rlpcm,
        is_word_bund,
        note,
        create_time,
        last_update
    FROM
        custom_word_moderation
    WHERE
        moderation_id=_moderation_id
    AND is_black=_is_black;
BEGIN

MOVE ABSOLUTE _index FROM custom_word_moderation_cursor;
RETURN QUERY FETCH _max_result FROM custom_word_moderation_cursor;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

The Error is:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1:  FETCH  $1  FROM  $2 
                ^
QUERY:   FETCH  $1  FROM  $2 
CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "get_pagination_custom_word_moderation" near line 18

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
SQL state: 42601
Context: SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "get_pagination_custom_word_moderation" near line 18
```

I think the problem is about how to return a fetch result form cursor.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not implemented. Cursors are intended to be returned as such, so that the *client* can fetch rows as he pleases. Especially for big results. You would define a function with [**`RETURNS refcursor`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-cursors.html#AEN57060) for that.

You *could* make it work with a [`FOR LOOP`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-FOR-LOOP) and explicit assignment of `OUT` variables, but that's tricky to combine with `RETURNS TABLE` ...
You would also have to [`OPEN` the cursor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-OPENING), because [`DECLARE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-DECLARATIONS) has a different meaning in the context of plpgsql than the same key word as [SQL `DECLARE` for cursors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-declare.html). And you would have to [`FETCH .. INTO ..`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-USING)

**Instead,** use a simple equivalent without cursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_pagination_custom_word_moderation(
                         _moderation_id bigint, _is_black boolean
                       , _index integer, _max_result integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(word_id bigint,
        word varchar,
        is_num_rlpcm boolean,
        is_word_bund boolean,
        note text,
        create_time timestamp,
        last_update timestamp) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT word_id
         ,word
         ,is_num_rlpcm
         ,is_word_bund
         ,note
         ,create_time
         ,last_update
   FROM   custom_word_moderation
   WHERE  moderation_id = _moderation_id
   AND    is_black = _is_black
   OFFSET _index
   LIMIT  _max_result;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or even simpler with an SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_pagination_custom_word_moderation(
                         _moderation_id bigint, _is_black boolean
                       , _index integer, _max_result integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(word_id bigint,
        word varchar,
        is_num_rlpcm boolean,
        is_word_bund boolean,
        note text,
        create_time timestamp,
        last_update timestamp) AS
$func$
   SELECT word_id
         ,word
         ,is_num_rlpcm
         ,is_word_bund
         ,note
         ,create_time
         ,last_update
   FROM   custom_word_moderation
   WHERE  moderation_id = $1
   AND    is_black = $2
   OFFSET $3
   LIMIT  $4;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

I am using `$n` notation in the function body, since parameter cannot be referenced by name in SQL functions before version 9.2.

If you actually want to return *all columns of a table*, you can further simplify:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_pagination_custom_word_moderation(
                         _moderation_id bigint, _is_black boolean
                       , _index integer, _max_result integer)
    RETURNS SETOF custom_word_moderation AS
$func$
   SELECT *
   FROM   custom_word_moderation
   WHERE  moderation_id = $1
   AND    is_black = $2
   OFFSET $3
   LIMIT  $4;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: Hi Erwin, Thanks for your reply, Yes i totally wrong about the way using cursor, so i modify my function to return refcursor(as you said) and then using FETCH(outside the function) after call the function(I do this in PHP as Transaction). But your suggestion using standard SELECT(not cursor) is contradict with this link http://microjet.ath.cx/WebWiki/ResultPaginationWithPostgresql.html. I just want to mention about performance different when using cursor or standard SELECT. sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: @Ahmad: Well, paging is a complicated matter. It all depends on your circumstances. For expensive queries and if you can keep connections open for distinct clients the cursor approach may improve performance.